# Execute Slot in different class

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I want to execute a slot in different class. Is it possible

```
 UI_CDSK Obj;
 connect(Obj.penDrive,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT( Obj.caller()));
```

This code is in different class and from this class i want to execute slot of different class(UI_CDSK )

Here penDrive and caller belongs to function UI_CDSK class and the mentioned code is in other class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little difficult without knowing the internals of UI_CDSK, but the correct syntax should be:

```
connect( Obj.penDrive, SIGNAL(clicked()), Obj, SLOT(caller()) );
```

So long as `caller()` is a public slot in UI_CDSK.

Comment: I gave like this but again showing error

My slot is public only
ERROR cannot convert parameter 3 from 'UI_CDSK' to 'const QObject *

Answer (score 0):

The connect method takes a pointer as receiver object, so if Obj isn't a pointer to a UI_CDSK object :

```
connect(Obj.pendrive, SIGNAL(clicked()), &Obj, SLOT(caller()));
```

Also this is probably already done (otherwise your compiler would have complained), but to use Qt signal slots mechanism, your UI_CDSK class must inherit from QObject.

It looks like the slot [doesn't need to be public](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/signalsandslots.html#slots).

Comment: I inherited QObject in UI_CDSK    

When i called caller using another slot in same class its working fine

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I had no idea slots did not have to be public when used in the Qt Signal/Slot context.